# React rendering with different content based on api response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const LinkList = () => {
    const [links, setLinks] = useState([]);
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/xyz';

    const hook = () => {
        console.log('effect');
        axios
            .get(url)
            .then(response => {
                setLinks(response.data.links);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log("couldn't fetch data", err))
    }

    useEffect(hook, []);

    return(
        <div>
            <p className=''> link list page </p>
            <ul>
                {
                    links.map((link, index) => <li key={index}> {link.link} </li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want the above component to render a different message, based on the response from the api being called. For example, if the api returns: {'message': 'No links found'}, then I don't want to render the ul tag with links but want to render a p tag with a message saying that no links were found.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Somehow no one linked to this yet: [React Documentation on Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be better to check the `links` array length instead? If it's empty - no links were returned by API.

```
{links.length > 0 ? (
   <ul>
      {links.map((link, index) => <li key={index}> {link.link} </li>)}
   </ul>
) : (
   <p>No links found!</p>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, wouldn't checking for the length of your "links" state be enough? you could render your message if the length is equals to 0